# What does $L^2((1+|\xi|^2)^sd\xi)$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, notation

In the most elementary contexts of Lebesgue measure, $L^2$ is the space of the lebesgue measurable functions $f$ such that $\int|f(x)|^2dx<\infty$.

For a general measure $\mu$, $L^2(\mu)$ is the space of the $\mu$-measurable functions $f$ such that $\int|f|^2d\mu<\infty$.

Could someone give me an explanation on the notation $L^2((1+|\xi|^2)^sd\xi)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual $L^2$ space with respect to the measure whose density / Radon-Nikodym derivative is given by

$$\frac{d\mu}{d\xi} = (1 + |\xi|^2)^s$$

That is, it's the set of functions for which

$$\int |f(\xi)|^2 (1 + |\xi|^2)^s \, d\xi < \infty$$

---

This is useful to study because these functions must satisfy much more stringent decay conditions at infinity than your usual $L^2(dx)$ functions. For example, $|f(\xi)| \lesssim |\xi|^{-1}$ isn't enough to guarantee that $f \in L^2(d\mu)$, because the integrand could still blow up like $|\xi|^{2s - 1}$ at infinity.

But Schwartz functions lie in this space for all $s$.